# Chrome omnibox suggestion always showing a "google search" as first suggestion

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

A recent Google Chrome update seems to have made the omnibox bar completely useless for me, I used to write the letter "i" and it used to put "imgur.com" as first suggestion (so just pressing `enter` was enough to enter the website), that's no longer the case, instead it is showing me as first suggestion a google search for the word "imgur" and that is not what I want at all, I tried do shift+supr to delete the suggestion with no success, I tried accessing imgur.com directly dozens of times in case it was a ranking algorithm gone awry but it did nothing as well.

[image: I hate chrome now]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This was a temporary bug. The fix details are here: https://superuser.com/questions/1440571/google-chrome-autocompleting-search-results-above-urls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps outlined in the link below fix the issue or at least improves things:

Basically open chrome://flags/ in chrome, search for the option
"Omnibox Google Drive Document suggestions" and disable it. Why exactly this improves it is not really clear. Even then it only seems to work for certain sites for some reasons, at least here.

https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/14/fix-chrome-prioritizing-search-words-over-visited-sites-in-address-bar/

Not very obvious though and annoying, as this is my favourite way of accessing sites.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I've updated it to at least have the gist of it in it.

Comment: Thanks! This was really annoying me. Luckily it's a bug so it'll be fixed at some point: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962599