# Google Chrome autocompleting search results above urls

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

After updating Chrome, I've noticed that when I enter the first letter of a commonly visited site like 't' for twitter, it no longer autocompletes to the twitter url, instead it is autocompleting a random google search result I've searched for once.

So even if I've visited a page thousands of times, it's still putting the google page as the first suggestion.  It's not suggesting new search results, but terms i've previously searched for.  But surely a URL I visit daily should rank above a google result I've only accessed once.

Is there any way I can fix this?  I know how to manually delete individual autocomplete suggestions, but I don't want to have to keep doing this.

Comment: Are you sure your history or any history related data wasn't removed during the update? That could be the reason why

Comment: Try using your chrome for like 1 week and see if that doesn't readjust all your most commonly typed urls. Lastly if you visit a website daily/frequently. You should make it a bookmark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome omnibox suggestion always showing a "google search" as first suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/1436390/chrome-omnibox-suggestion-always-showing-a-google-search-as-first-suggestion)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962599

Work-around:

- Go to: `chrome://flags/`
- Search for `Omnibox Google Drive Document suggestions`
- Disable `Omnibox Google Drive Document suggestions`
- Relaunch chrome

Source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/bsfyi5/has_the_address_bar_algorithm_gotten_worse/)