# Google Chrome Address Bar Prediction Prioritize Search Instead of Frequency of Success Guess

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I Just update my google chrome to

> Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I noticed something wasn't right, or maybe settings have been changed. Previous prediction in the address bar based on confidence level. Confidence level can be found at `chrome://predictors/`. However, now if I search something in the address bar, the next time the search term will be the first prediction, always.

For example if I type `g` in my address bar, the predictor will show `google.com`. Then I type `game` in my address bar and hit enter for a google search. The next time I type `g` in my address bar, `game` will show up even though `google.com` confidence level is above 0.9

I could not find a setting relate to this problem. If anyone know please help.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome autocompleting search results above urls](https://superuser.com/questions/1440571/google-chrome-autocompleting-search-results-above-urls)

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by a Chrome bug:

[Issue 962599: Search autofills now default to the most recent query instead of the most-searched query](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962599)

It was fixed by June 2019 or so, which corresponds to the date this Question was asked.

> Comment 33 by jdonnelly@chromium.org on Thu, Jun 20, 2019, 7:50 PM PDT
>
> I sincerely apologize to everyone affected by this issue. I'm happy to report that the problem should now be addressed. If you restart Chrome, you should start seeing your most visited sites/URLs as the default again.